# Android Camera: setSceneMode() has no effect on android V21

Tags: android, android-camera

I am working on custom camera and using deprecated `Camera` api's instead of `Camera2` api's  in Android L but I am facing lots issues in preview. One of them is, It is showing dark preview and another problem is `setSceneMode` and `setColorEffects` making no effect. Please let me know the workaround if any one out there used deprecated camera api's in v21.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a high FPS which may produce a dark preview in some devices, because a high FPS lowers the exposure compensation. Setting it to a variable range instead of a fixed one can solve the problem for the devices that present such issue.

A device may return a set of supported ranges such as for example: [10-15, 15-30, 30-30]. In this example you would pick up any of the variable ones, and avoid the fixed one [30-30]. Note that fixed ranges are meant to be for video only.

Comment: getSupportedPreviewFpsRange() returned 15000 to 15000, 24000 to 24000,   15000 to 30000,30000 to 30000  so how can I change it 15 to 25.

Comment: The returned range is different per device, is not important that is 15 to 25, what is important is that is variable and not fixed. So that means to avoid (15-15, 24-24 and 30-30), And to choose a variable one, in your case 15-30. My solution was to recurse the FPS list and find a variable FPS range. And ensure a initial exposure balance of 0.

Comment: Oh my goodness.. You solved my problem.. but in my nexus 7(v21) coloreffects are not working, scene mode works fine. In nexus 5(v21) scene and color both are working fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In my Nexus 9 (v21) scenes mode are not working. Actually only works the "sunset" scene, the rest of scenes do not work at all, and is driving me nuts. Are you using any special code to set the scene? Next is my code: Camera.Parameters pm = _camera.getParameters(); pm.setSceneMode(Parameters.SCENE_MODE_NIGHT); _camera.setParameter(pm);

Comment: Did you check the picture taken. In my nexus 7, effects are not showing in the preview but effects are perfectly applied to taken pictures. I guess it is something to do with fps.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Camera.Parameters is deprecated.

> This class was deprecated in API level 21.
>   We recommend using the new android.hardware.camera2 API for new applications.

**[Android Developer - Camera.Parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html)**

You should use this instead for devices with API level > 21:

**[Android Developer - android.hardware.camera2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)**

Comment: I know its deprecated. It just does not work on Nexus 7 even if you try using Camera 2 apis

Comment: `Turns out Camera.Parameters is deprecated.` only parameter or all camera api?)) a funny answer